# I prooved something that does not seem right on a Real Analysis book, set theory problem. Help me find where it's wrong and how to solve the problem.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $$f: \mathcal{P}(A) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(A)$$ be a function defined on the power set of set $A$, and $X,Y,X_{\lambda}$ are subsets of $A$.

$f$ has two properties, as follows:
$$X\subset Y \Rightarrow f(Y) \subset f(X), \hspace{1cm} \text{and} \hspace{1cm} f(f(X))=X.$$

Show that $$f(\cup X_{\lambda})=\cap f(X_{\lambda}),$$ and
$$f(\cap X_{\lambda})=\cup f(X_{\lambda}).$$

By using properties of $f$, I showed that $A$ must be **empty**. The proof goes like this:

\begin{align}
& f(X_{\lambda}) \subset \cup f(X_{\lambda}) \\
\Rightarrow & f(\cup f(X_{\lambda})) \subset f(f(X_{\lambda}))\\
\Rightarrow &  \cup f(f(X_{\lambda})) \subset X_{\lambda}\\
\Rightarrow & \cup X_{\lambda} \subset X_{\lambda}\\
\Rightarrow &  \cup X_{\lambda} = X_{\lambda}
\end{align}

But that is only possible if all the sets $X_{\lambda}$ are equal. Since $X_{\lambda}$ are arbitrary subsets of $A$, requiring that all of them must be equal, makes $A$ an empty set.

PS: Someone on Mathoverflow said I misread a $\cap$ as a $\cup$, but I can't see where.

Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is $X_\lambda$? I assume you mean some arbitrary family of subsets, $(X_\lambda)_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$? So, $\lambda$ is an index?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: You initially state that $X$ and $X_\lambda$ are given, but then say "since $X_\lambda$ are arbitrary subsets of $A$....".

Comment: They're all just arbitrary subsets of A

Comment: In the third line you wrote $\cup$ when you should have written $\cap$ according to the stated property of the function, which yields a trivially true statement.

Comment: Are you sure these properties don't just hold for the given index set?

Comment: Note that for any set $A$ there is at least one function that satisfies the conditions above, namely $f(X)=A-X$ so you may want to reassess your reasoning and find your mistake

Comment: @CharlesHudgins in the third line I used that f(union)=union(f), that's a property of any function that's listed in my book.

Comment: @Conrad Thanks! I'll give that a thought.

Comment: Why do you claim that $f(\cup f(X_{\lambda}))=\cup f(f(X_{\lambda}))$; this is simply not true here as by the properties of $f$ you have $f(\cup f(X_{\lambda}))\subset f(f(X_{\lambda}))$ for every $\lambda$ so on the right hand side you have intersection not union

Comment: For any function there's a property that states $f(A \cup B)=f(A)\cup f(B)$, I used it here for arbitrary union of sets, which I hope it's true. I think that's where I'm wrong, but I can't see why this statement that works for two sets wouldn't work for an arbitrary union of sets.

Comment: @nileebolt Your function is a function on a power set, not a function on sets, so you cannot use the function on sets rules freely. Not every power set function arises from a set function, say $g$, as $A \mapsto g(A)$. If you like, you've written a proof that your $f$ is one such function.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Ooh, now I see. I thought that I could use the properties for functions defined on sets freely. Thank you guys so much, now I'll try to solve the problem.